# Returning Flux<String> from Spring WebFlux returns one string instead of array of strings in JSON

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

new to Spring WebFlux, trying to return array of strings in one endpoint and for some reason it returns one concatenated string istead of JSON array.

Wrapping it with some class solves the problem but wonder how to actually return array of strings? Returning for example `Array<String>` works as expected

```
class Wrapper(val data: String) {

@RestController
class Test() {
     @RequestMapping("/wrapped") // Returns valid JSON array: [{"value":"Hello"},{"value":"World"}]
     fun b() = Flux.just(Wrapper("Hello"),Wrapper("World"))
     @RequestMapping("/raw") // Returns not valid JSON with just one concatenated string: HelloWorld
     fun a() = Flux.just("Hello", "World")
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Got an answer from Sébastien Deleuze (Spring framework committer) in Twitter https://twitter.com/sdeleuze/status/956136517348610048

> Indeed when element type is String, the handler method is expected to provide directly well formed JSON String chunks, no serialization with Jackson is involved.

Comment: So what do we need to do if we want to have the strings seperated from each other?

Comment: The answer is clear: You have to wrap it. The answer above works; although you could do it like this as well: `fun a() = Flux.just("Hello", "World").collectList()`

Comment: Converting to a list is loosing reactivness

Comment: Indeed the answer is correct. This is also covered in the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs-jackson

Comment: It does not loose reactivness since you get a Mono

Comment: @sam I've tested it myself, you will lose reactiveness in the elements. If you add `delayElements()`, you will see that it is not streaming individual element one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case replacing Flux with Mono<List< String>> as suggested in the official spring documentation was not fixing the problem immediately.

I was calling the below method that resided in a different micro service:

```
 public Mono<List<String>> getProductIds(String userId) {

    LOG.info("Will get productIds for user with id={}", userId);
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> getUserProductIds(userId));

 }

 private List<String> getUserProductIds(String userId) {...
```

And using the code below for the call:

```
 public Mono<List<String>> getAssociatedProductIds(String userId) {
    String url = userProductServiceUrl + "/" + userId;


    return webClient.get().uri(url).retrieve().bodyToFlux(String).collectList()
            .onErrorMap(WebClientResponseException.class, ex -> handleException(ex));
}
```

However I was getting something like [["productId1","productId2"]] as a return value, which would create problems down the code since it was interpreted as an array with two strings:

```
 p.e.m.c.event.services.ProdutcServiceImpl  : getProducts: retrieving events for [%5B%22productId1%22, %22productId2%22%5D]
```

The fix for this was to use bodyToMono in the webClient builder and pass a ParameterizedTypeReference:

```
return webClient.get().uri(url).retrieve().bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {})
            .onErrorMap(WebClientResponseException.class, ex -> handleException(ex));
```